# Declaring associations in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

Hopefully I don't get flamed for this one too bad - I've tried my very hardest to find an answer to no avail.

I was wondering if someone could help me figure out how to properly declare associations in Ruby on Rails (3). At the moment, I have 3 models:

```
#room.rb
class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :check_ins
end

#check_in.rb
class CheckIn < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :room
end

#user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :check_in
end
```

So far, I haven't done any migrations to add foreign_key columns to any of my tables (does Rails do this for you?).

I'm confused about why the command `CheckIn.first.user` returns `nil` whereas the command `User.first.check_in` returns `SQLite3::SQLException: no such column`. The same happens with respect to `CheckIn.first.room` and `Room.first.check_ins`, respectively. What would I need to do in order to have `User.first.check_in` return the CheckIn object associated with the first user and `Room.first.check_ins` return the set of CheckIns associated with the first Room?

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Charlie

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How did you originally generate these models?  Did you just make the model files, or did you use rails' model generator (which also generates a migration for you)?

```
#room.rb
class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :check_ins
end

#check_in.rb
class CheckIn < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :room
end

#user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :check_in
  has_one :room, :through => :check_in
end
```

In db/migrations/34612525162_something_something.rb You need to make sure you have migrations that set these tables up for you.  The easiest way for you to do it would be to run this command in a console, modify the commands to use the fields you want, the *_id fields are required for your associations to work:

```
rails generate model user name:string email:string otherfield:integer
rails generate model check_in user_id:integer room_id:integer
rails generate model room number:integer
```

Note that these will also generate model files for you, since you already have these 3 model files it'll ask you if you want to overwrite them, or skip the files.  You can skip them and it should be just fine.  **If you already had the migrations for part of the data in these models then you can just add the user_id and room_id fields to the check_in model by running this generator instead**:

```
rails generate migration AddIdsToCheckIn user_id:integer room_id:integer
```

For rails 2.3.x replace `rails generate` with `script/generate`.  Next you can inspect your migration(s) by opening the files up in `db/migrate.rb` and modify them there if you need to.  Finally, run the migrations:

```
rake db:migrate
```

And it should work out for you.  Note that I added a `has_one, :through =>` relationship to User - this is so that you can do `@user.room` without having to make 3 chains: `@user.check_in.room`

Comment: Great answer - very descriptive! The key idea that I was missing that was that I needed to add the user_id and room_id columns to check_in via a migration. Also, thanks for the tip on the `:through` idea - that'll come in handy!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the migrations yourself (or if you aren't live, you can modify an existing migration). Basically, you need to give the belongs_to side of the relationship a foreign key.

Comment: This worked out great! The command that I ended up using to generate such a migration (for anyone who might find this in the future) was `rails g migration add_room_id_to_check_ins room_id:integer` (obviously followed by a `rake db:migrate`). Thanks for the help!

Comment: @candrews apparently I type too slow :p

Comment: haha, well, they were both good answers, one was just a bit faster. I was kind of torn =p

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no reason to get flamed don't worry :) It seems here that you are trying to do a one to many association, but you're actually doing a many to many one.

If a user has one check in, it means that he/she has one room. So, you could just have :

user has_one room
room belongs to user

and room has a user_id.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Haha, well thank you for the confidence boost =p I should have been more a little less narrow in my question - there are other attributes to CheckIn that make it so that it makes sense to have CheckIn be its own model. Kevin's answer pointed me in the right direction, though, so I've got it figured out. Thank you!